# url rewrite with htaccess

Tags: php, html, .htaccess, redirect, url-rewriting

i want rewrite my url
this is my index.html page

```
<a href="http://localhost/htac/index.php?url=main&page=1">Main</a> <br>
<a href="http://localhost/htac/index.php?url=about&page=2">About</a> <br>
<a href="http://localhost/htac/index.php?url=contact&page=3">Contact</a> <br>
```

this is my .htacees file

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f    
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d    
RewriteRule ^/([a-z])/([0-9])?$ index.php?url=$1&page=$2 [L]
```

i want change my url to

```
http://localhost/htac/index/about/2 (http://localhost/htac/index/{url}/{page})
```

but url is :

```
http://localhost/htac/index.php?url=about&page=2
```

Comment: So did you try `http://localhost/htac/index/about/2` to see if it resolves?

Comment: no, not working this link
Not Found

The requested URL /htac/index/about/2 was not found on this server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have your **`/htac/.htaccess`** like this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /htac/

# external redirect from actual URL to pretty one
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index\.php\?url=([^\s&]+)&page=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1/%2? [R=302,L,NE]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f    
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d    
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ index.php?url=$1&page=$2 [L,QSA]
```

You need to change source of your HTML to have links as: `<a href="http://localhost/htac/main/1">Main</a>`

Comment: IMO `/index/` should also be avoided from pretty URL. That's why I wrote a note on what the pretty URL should be.

Comment: i want rewrite with htacces

Comment: @Beginner add this code to htaccess this is for htaccess

Comment: @Beginner Then start by using a valid URL! The answer of anubhava is correct.

Comment: @anubhava ps. I would also add the `NC` parameter.

Comment: @Beginner: Rules can redirect `http://localhost/htac/index.php?url=about&page=2` from `http://localhost/htac/about/2` but you should still change your HTML source to have correct pretty URLs.

Comment: @GuyT: Actually this pattern `^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$` doesn't need `NC` (ignore case) flag.

Comment: @Beginner: Check my edited answer now that will redirect `http://localhost/htac/index.php?url=about&page=2` to  `http://localhost/htac/about/2`

Comment: @anubhava Why isn't it necessary to indlude the `NC` flag in that kind of pattern?

Comment: @GuyT: It is because `^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$` will match **anything** except 2 slashes. So it will match `abc/123` as well as `ABC/123` (it is case agnostic already).

Comment: @anubhava That's my point. What if `abc/123` contains other data then `ABC/123`?

Comment: URL can have text in lowercase or uppercase or mixed. All those cases will be matched by `^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$` without requiring any `NC` flag. You can test it to see it matching.